# Move cursor to the beginning of the multiple selected lines visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you move your cursor to the beginning of multiple selected lines in VScode ? i know that `shift+alt+i` is to go the end of the line but couldn't find the reverse. Don't confuse my question with the start of the document.

Comment: What about the 'home' key?

Comment: I normally just hit `Home` twice.

Comment: Updated my question. I'm looking for multiple lines shortcut.

Comment: I don't think there's one. Do `shift+alt+i`, and then hit `home`. If you want to, there are some extensions that let you map a sequence of commands to a single hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a keybinding that uses a macro extension to run multiple commands, like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

```
  {
    "key": "home",    // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
        "cursorLineStart"   // goto start of line before any leading whitespace
        // "cursorHome"     // goto start of text on each line
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  }
```

It works really nicely, with one multi-line selection or multiple selections:

[image: multi-selection cursor home demo]